# Best way to integrate OpenId connect / (Keycloak) with Django and Django Rest framework

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, keycloak, openid-connect

I'm looking for advice on the best way to integrate Django / Django Rest Framework with OpenId connect (we're using Keycloak but I think  using the protocol is probably more flexible).

There seems to be several option out there, but it would be good to have something that works as seamlessly as possible with Django and DRF – so session and API authentication working like the baked in Django version, and ideally access to external logon screens if using admin/DRF API endpoint. What is straightforward to set up and well supported?

What I will ultimately be doing is trying to change an existing Django/React application, but for the purposes of this discussion let's assume it's a basic application something like the ones set up in the Django tutorial and Django Rest framework quickstart  (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial01/ to tutorial01 and https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/).

I hope that's enough as I fairly new to this – I can create some sort of simple application in Github if this isn't a clear enough basis for a discussion.

Any help would be much appreciated. Even better if you have an example (!).

Comment: hi, did you find any solution regarding this? I am also looking for a similar solution. Would love some advice

Comment: Hi, I'll write more when I have finished the integration - but the short answer to your question is that I eventually settled on: mozilla-django-oidc - https://mozilla-django-oidc.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html which is fairly lightweight and seems to be supported. The only specific comment I have so far in terms of the integration with keycloak is that I had to set: OIDC_RP_SIGN_ALGO = "RS256" for it to work. Hope that works for you.